# Prevent invalid memory access valgrind C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to understand why valgrind is screaming at me (pretty new to C programming and valgrind).
I implemented a generic linked list (found in github - thanks to fabianosalles) that holds struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct symbol_entity
{
    /* Symbol name */
    char *name;
    /* Symbol address */
    unsigned int address;
    /* Indicates if symbol is extern */
    bool is_extern;
    /* Indicates if symbol is entry */
    bool is_entry;
    /* Indicates if symbol is instruction */
    bool is_instruction;
    /* Indicates if symbol is opcode */
    bool is_opcode;
} symbol_entity;
```

Furthermore, I implemented a method that insert data to the linked list called add_symbol_to_list_with_result.
It returns true and set result_symbol to the one who was added to list in case added successfully. 
Otherwise if symbol already exists it returns false and should initialize result_symbol to null. 
(maybe there is a better choice, you are more than welcome to suggest!)

```
bool add_symbol_to_list_with_result(linked_list **symbols, char *name, bool is_extern, bool is_entry, bool is_instruction, bool is_opcode, unsigned int address, symbol_entity **result_symbol)
{
    *result_symbol = (symbol_entity *)verified_malloc(sizeof(symbol_entity));
    (*result_symbol)->name = verified_malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name));
    strncpy((*result_symbol)->name, name, strlen(name));
    (*result_symbol)->is_extern = is_extern;
    (*result_symbol)->is_entry = is_entry;
    (*result_symbol)->is_instruction = is_instruction;
    (*result_symbol)->address = address;
    (*result_symbol)->is_opcode = is_opcode;
    if (!list_contains(*symbols, *result_symbol))
    {
        list_add(*symbols, *result_symbol);
        return TRUE;
    }
    free(*result_symbol);
    result_symbol = NULL;
    return FALSE;
}
```

list_add looks like:

```
void list_add(linked_list *list, void *data)
{
    node_item *newNode;
    if (list != NULL && data != NULL)
    {
        newNode = verified_malloc(sizeof(node_item));
        newNode->data = verified_malloc(list->data_size);
        memcpy(newNode->data, data, list->data_size);
        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = newNode;
            list->tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = newNode;
            list->tail = newNode;
        }
        list->count++;
    }
}
```

and of course verified malloc looks like:

```
void *verified_malloc(long size)
{
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fatal error! Memory allocation failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

add_symbol_to_list_with_result method get called multiple times, and I can see in valgrind output stuff like that:

```
==9179==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9179==    at 0x402D17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==9179==    by 0x804C074: verified_malloc (in /home/user/.....)
==9179==    by 0x804A0F5: list_add (in /home/user/.....)
==9179==    by 0x804B4E6: add_symbol_to_list_with_result (in /home/user/.....)
=
.
.
.
==9179==  Address 0x4263d94 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==9179==    at 0x402D17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==9179==    by 0x804C074: verified_malloc (in /home/user/.....)
==9179==    by 0x804B454: add_symbol_to_list_with_result (in /home/user/.....)
```

Any help with this type of output?
EDIT:
symbols is declared in a different C file:
linked_list *symbols;
linked_list initialized with this method:

```
linked_list *list_create(int dataSize, callback_free free_callback, callback_compare compare_callback)
{
    linked_list *list;
    if (dataSize > 0)
    {
        /* Initialize parameters in linked list */
        list = (linked_list *)verified_malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
        list->count = 0;
        list->data_size = dataSize;
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;
        list->callback_free = free_callback;
        list->callback_compare = compare_callback;
    }
    return list;
}
```

and is passes to multiple methods using &symbols

Comment: You should write your error messages to stderr, not stdout.  And of course, always end each printed line with a newline character.

Comment: If you're copying a string, you need to allocate strlen+1 bytes, to allow room for the null terminator.

Comment: It looks like you aren't null-terminating `name` in your allocated structure.  You're allocating enough characters for the name itself, but not the null character.  You then use `strncpy` to write to it, so you end up with a string that is not null-terminated, and you have no way of telling where it ends.

Comment: Looking good for the second error in valgrind, first one still appears @TomKarzes

Comment: Please show where you get **symbols from (which goes into bool add_symbol_to_list_with_result).

Comment: `result_symbol = NULL` is pointless in your function; maybe you wanted `*result_symbol = NULL` to null out the pointer that was stored there which is free now?  The freed pointer was written into a location indicated by the caller via `result_symbol`, and that now invalid value is still there after the function has returned.

Comment: @sidcoder, I've added the code you asked for.

Comment: @Kaz, true, second option you pointed out is the right one

Comment: Never use `strncpy()` unless you understand *exactly* what it does and you really want that.  Some people seem to take it for a safer `strcpy()`, but it's not.  In some ways it's even riskier.  However, with just a little priming, `strcat()` can be used for the job that people who don't read docs carefully may think `strncpy()` will do.

Comment: In a few months, `strdup` will finally be part of the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
(*result_symbol)->name = verified_malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name)+1));
```

to account for the required "\0" at end of string.

And after line

```
strncpy((*result_symbol)->name, name, strlen(name));
```

include the line

```
(*result_symbol)->name[strlen(name)]='\0'
```

just to be sure.

**Furthermore**, I would guess an allocation problem for `**symbol` which goes into `bool add_symbol_to_list_with_result` - please show the allocation for `**symbol`.

**Question**

Is `list->data_size` equal to `sizeof(symbol_entity)`?

```
memcpy(newNode->data, data, list->data_size);
```

**Please try**

```
memcpy(newNode->data, data, sizeof(symbol_entity));
```

**Memory handling**
Please note that your memory handling of `*result_symbol` is not accurate: 
 In case of return TRUE, you keep `*result_symbol` completely, although only char array of name pointer would be required (`*result_symbol` was copied.)

 In case of return FALSE, you free `*result_symbol`, but not the name pointer.

 In both cases some memory is lost.

**Missing code**
Yes, the additional code which you provided is useful. However, as larger parts, like the other `typedef struct`definitions and any memory handling above the provided subroutines is missing, ... I can not see anything more. In the beginning, you refer to github. Do you have link to more (the full) code?

Comment: Looks like it fixed the second part only:
Address 0x4263d94 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd.
  First part is still there

Comment: Added according your request